# What is the precession of the star S62?

Tags: star, black-hole

What is the angle of precession of the star S62 orbiting the Milky Way supermassive black hole?

Comment: This is [cross-posted from Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538660/83380) but in an even shorter and less clear form than it was there! `-1` because none of the concerns raised in comments there were addressed there or here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S62_(star)) it is 10 degrees.  Wikipedia cites [Peißker et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.02341.pdf), 
which uses the formula:
$$\Delta\phi = \frac{6\pi G}{c^2}\frac{M}{a(1-e^2)}$$ to derive a relativistic periapse shift of 9.9 degrees per orbit.

Comment: 9.9 degrees per orbit is not the correct value. If you do the numerical calculation you'll find 1.26 degrees. The value given in Peissker's paper is wrong (Peissker did agree) and so is the publication in Wikipedia.